# Sudden loss of dependencies in Eclipse Gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I'm working with a Gradle project in Eclipse Oxygen with Java 8 and Gradle wrapper 4.6.

When i tried to add a new dependency `compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'` and refresh the project, all the "Project and External Dependencies" folder disappeared without a trace, which stops my project running from Eclipse (it can run through Gradle Run task though).

Removing the newly added dependency does not save me. Neither `gradlew cleanEclipse & gradlew eclipse` nor refreshing the project countless times.

I also attempted to clear the cache and forced project to rebuild when reimport, but no "Project and External Dependencies" shows up.

What should i do to bring back the old dependencies?

Here is my `build.gradle`

```
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'
// Apply the plugin to be runnable
apply plugin: 'application'
// Apply the eclipse plugin to import project on other machines
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
// JUnit 5
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

// Define the entry point
mainClassName = 'meshIneBits.MeshIneBitsMain'
applicationName = 'MeshIneBits'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    compile 'org.processing:core:3.3.5'
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2'
    compile 'org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2'

    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-linux-amd64"
    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-linux-armv6"
    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-linux-armv6hf"
    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-linux-i586"
    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-macosx-universal"
    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-windows-amd64"
    runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:2.3.2:natives-windows-i586"

    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-linux-amd64"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-linux-armv6"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-linux-armv6hf"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-linux-i586"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-macosx-universal"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-solaris-i586"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-windows-amd64"
    runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.3.2:natives-windows-i586"

    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0',
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.1.0')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0',
            'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.1.0')
}

eclipse {
    project.natures 'org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature'
    classpath {
        file {
            defaultOutputDir = file('bin/main')
            whenMerged {
                //change output folder for tests
                def testsrc = entries.find { it.path == 'src/test/java' }
                testsrc.output = "bin/test"

                def testres = entries.find { it.path == 'src/test/resources' }
                testres.output = "bin/test"

                // Remove local ref for libs
                entries.removeAll{ it.kind == "lib" }
            }
            containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/5', 'org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer' }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.1.0' }
}

jar {
    baseName = applicationName
    version = '0.2.0'
    manifest { attributes  'Main-Class' : mainClassName }
}
```

Edit:
After switching to IntelliJ, the problem is solved (i used the same folder of project). So i think this is a problem in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem where the "Project and External Dependencies" folder disappeared.  It instead showed as 'org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer'.

If you do not see that line, then it needs to be added to the .classpath file.

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleclasspathcontainer" />
```

The fix that worked for me was closing Eclipse, and running

```
gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse
```

then opening Eclipse and adding the Gradle nature to the project.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem when I refactor the project name.

Following steps solve my problem:

1. add `eclipse` plugin to `build.gradle`
2. right click `build.gradle`, choose `gradle` then select `refresh gradle project`

only `refresh gradle project` didn't help me.